# Disable all mouse messages on control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a graph control that plots data points. The data points are plotted as 1 point per pixel. If the number of data points get larger than a certain amount, or the size of the window is increased the performance of the plotting when you move your mouse over the control suffers.  If you move quickly the plotting actually stops during the motion.

Is there a way to disable all the messages when the mouse is over that control except for button clicks?

I have not been able to find anything.

Comment: Is this a graph control for which you have access to the source code or a library component you are using?  Also, what do you mean by _button clicks_ ?

Comment: I do not have access to the source code for the graph control, it's a library component.  I mean mouse clicks.  So I want to be able to pass mouse clicks.

Comment: Derive your own class from that control class.  Override OnMouseMove(), don't call base.OnMouseMove().  Build > Build and drop it from the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I believe that it should be sufficient to filter out MouseMove messages sent to the control.  This can be accomplished by having the Form implement [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=netframework-4.7.2) similar to the example presented below.  Returning `true` from `IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage` prevents the message from being sent to the control (a panel in the example).  A registered filter is active application wide, so it is added/removed when the form actives/deactivates.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    private Panel pnl;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pnl = new Panel { Size = new Size(200, 200), Location = new Point(20, 20), BackColor = Color.Aqua };
        Controls.Add(pnl);
        pnl.Click += panel_Click;
        pnl.MouseMove += panel_MouseMove;
        pnl.MouseHover += panel_MouseHover;

    }

    private void panel_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    {
        // this should not occur
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // this should not occur
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void panel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("panel clicked");
    }

    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);
        // install message filter when form activates
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDeactivate(e);
        // remove message filter when form deactivates
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }

    bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        bool handled = false;
        if (m.HWnd == pnl.Handle && (WM) m.Msg == WM.MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }

    public  enum WM : int
    {
        #region Mouse Messages
        MOUSEFIRST = 0x200,
        MOUSEMOVE = 0x200,
        LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201,
        LBUTTONUP = 0x202,
        LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203,
        RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204,
        RBUTTONUP = 0x205,
        RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x206,
        MBUTTONDOWN = 0x207,
        MBUTTONUP = 0x208,
        MBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x209,
        MOUSELAST = 0x209
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution is correct however, in this case it doesn't work.  I have determined this is purely a graphics performance issue.  If I plot less items in the graph such as not plotting a fill for example then there is no issue. I did see this solution but yours is much easier to understand than the others!  Very well done thanks.

Comment: @Tom, you did not mention which chart control you are using, but many WinForm chart controls are pigs (especially the MS/Dundas control in the DataVisualization namespace).  I've seen some good performance claims stated about [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/), but I have only played with it myself.

Comment: This is the scope component from Mitov.com.  I think i may have a solution but I'm not sure how to implement it.  The faster the mouse moves over the control, the more the plotting slows down. So if I can get the mouse to not report every motion when moving fast it might work.